# Can php xpath search forward using the following axis only until a specific tag?

Tags: php, xpath

I am trying to parse a badly formed html table:

A couple of lines of this are:

```
  Food:</b> Yes<b><br>
 Pool: </b>Beach<b></b><b><br>
  Centre:</b> Yes<b><br>
```

Uding php's domdocument xpath I am able to select all the title tags like Food, center and pool, but once I have each I would like to search forward until I hit the next title tag.

I know that regex can look forward until a specific pattern. Can xpath do the same for a specifc tag?

Thanks,

Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using following-sibling::br[1]/following-sibling::text()[1] appears to be what you need.

However when doing complex queries on poorly structured data the best advice is often to start by doing an XSLT transformation to create a better structure.

Comment: Michael, Basic question: In the context of xpath what does the '::' mean in plain english. ( like in eg following-sibling::text()[1] )

Comment: Before '::' is the name of an axis, which selects a set of nodes in the tree. After '::' is a node-test, which filters those nodes according to the kind of node and/or the node name. The node-test text() filters the results to include only text nodes.